# A pair of dice are rolled. It is known that the sum of those equals to 6

Tags: summation, dice

A pair of dice are rolled. It is known that the sum of those equals to 6. What is the probability that the product of two dices is equal to 5 or 9?

Comment: I consider those cases here (5,1)(1,5)(4,2)(2,4)(3,3)(3,3). 
And the solution then is:
 
4/6 = 2/3

My questioin is: should i count (3,3) twice here?

Comment: No,you should count it only once. In the sample space obtained, there is only one outcome of (3,3).

Comment: It may help if you imagine the dice to be of two different colours, say red (R) & green (G). There are 2 ways to get (1, 5) -> (R1, G5) and (R5, G1). But there's only one way to get (3, 3) -> (R3, G3)

Answer (score 1):

For a problem this small-scale, counting the possibilities is the easiest option. To roll a sum of 6, there are exactly five possible rolls: (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,2), and (5,1) (denoting a roll as (first dice, second dice)). Three of those meet the product requirement, so the final answer is $\frac{3}{5}$.

Note that you *do not* count (3,3) twice, because there are not two distinct situations that produce that result. In combinatorics, when double-counting is necessary, it can only be necessary because there are two possible circumstances yielding the same result. That usually means that you're not counting the right things anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It will help to write the sample space of the experiment of rolling a die and having a sum equalling $6$ as: {$(1,5) (2,4) (3,3) (4,2) (5,1)$}. Out of this two cases {$(1,5) (5,1)$} satisfy the product of $5$ and one case {$(3,3)$} with a product of $9$. The total number of cases with a product of either $5$ or $9$ is $3$.

---

Hence, we have a probability (using conditional probability) of $$\frac{3}{5}$$

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

For sum as 6, Sample space = {$(1,5) (2,4) (3,3) (4,2) (5,1)$} $= 5$

For product as 5 or 9, Favourable case = {$(1,5) (3,3) (5,1)$} $= 3$

Probability = $\frac{3}{5}$